# Permission Error While running a script in in macOS

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I am trying to open PowerPoint and make a new file, using the script editor. But I am receiving this error, "Can’t set «class pptP» to make new «class pptP» with properties {name:"Test"}. Access not allowed." How can I fix this issue? Please help

Code:

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate

    set presentation to make new presentation with properties {name:"Test"}
    
end tell
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to modify the script to make it work? Have you done some research before posting? This question needs (1) more detail and clarity and (2) more understanding of what you ask (includes research done before)

Comment: Why are you using `presentation` as a variable name? It's the name of a class and the error message is trying to tell you not to do that. Use something —like 'newDoc'— that doesn't already have a meaning.